# Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError in using lottie library

Tags: android, lottie

In my SplashActivity I get settings from remote API and show animation by Lottie library simultaneously and in each cycle of animation if settings loaded successfully I redirect the user to the next activity, if not I play the animation again and this cycle will continue until settings loaded

I get

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

for some of the users

What is the cause of this exception and how can I solve it?

**Firebase console crash log Stack trace**:

> ```
> Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.animation.keyframe.BaseKeyframeAnimation.getCurrentKeyframe(BaseKeyframeAnimation.java:86)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.animation.keyframe.BaseKeyframeAnimation.setProgress(BaseKeyframeAnimation.java:60)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.animation.keyframe.TransformKeyframeAnimation.setProgress(TransformKeyframeAnimation.java:124)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.model.layer.BaseLayer.setProgress(BaseLayer.java:491)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.model.layer.CompositionLayer.setProgress(CompositionLayer.java:130)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.model.layer.CompositionLayer.setProgress(CompositionLayer.java:148)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.model.layer.CompositionLayer.setProgress(CompositionLayer.java:148)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.model.layer.CompositionLayer.setProgress(CompositionLayer.java:148)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable$1.onAnimationUpdate(LottieDrawable.java:73)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.BaseLottieAnimator.notifyUpdate(BaseLottieAnimator.java:88)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.LottieValueAnimator.setFrame(LottieValueAnimator.java:158)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.LottieValueAnimator.playAnimation(LottieValueAnimator.java:207)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.playAnimation(LottieDrawable.java:387)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView.playAnimation(LottieAnimationView.java:511)
>            at com.beroozresaan.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity$1.onAnimationEnd(SplashActivity.java:196)
>            at android.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(Animator.java:552)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.BaseLottieAnimator.notifyEnd(BaseLottieAnimator.java:73)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.LottieValueAnimator.endAnimation(LottieValueAnimator.java:216)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.playAnimation(LottieDrawable.java:391)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView.playAnimation(LottieAnimationView.java:511)
>            at com.beroozresaan.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity$1.onAnimationEnd(SplashActivity.java:196)
>            at android.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(Animator.java:552)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.BaseLottieAnimator.notifyEnd(BaseLottieAnimator.java:73)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.LottieValueAnimator.endAnimation(LottieValueAnimator.java:216)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.playAnimation(LottieDrawable.java:391)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView.playAnimation(LottieAnimationView.java:511)
>            at com.beroozresaan.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity$1.onAnimationEnd(SplashActivity.java:196)
>            at android.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(Animator.java:552)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.BaseLottieAnimator.notifyEnd(BaseLottieAnimator.java:73)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.LottieValueAnimator.endAnimation(LottieValueAnimator.java:216)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.playAnimation(LottieDrawable.java:391)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView.playAnimation(LottieAnimationView.java:511)
>            at com.beroozresaan.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity$1.onAnimationEnd(SplashActivity.java:196)
>            at android.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(Animator.java:552)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.BaseLottieAnimator.notifyEnd(BaseLottieAnimator.java:73)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.LottieValueAnimator.endAnimation(LottieValueAnimator.java:216)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.playAnimation(LottieDrawable.java:391)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView.playAnimation(LottieAnimationView.java:511)
>            at com.beroozresaan.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity$1.onAnimationEnd(SplashActivity.java:196)
>            at android.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(Animator.java:552)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.BaseLottieAnimator.notifyEnd(BaseLottieAnimator.java:73)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.LottieValueAnimator.endAnimation(LottieValueAnimator.java:216)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.playAnimation(LottieDrawable.java:391)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView.playAnimation(LottieAnimationView.java:511)
>            at com.beroozresaan.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity$1.onAnimationEnd(SplashActivity.java:196)
>            at android.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(Animator.java:552)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.BaseLottieAnimator.notifyEnd(BaseLottieAnimator.java:73)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.LottieValueAnimator.endAnimation(LottieValueAnimator.java:216)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.playAnimation(LottieDrawable.java:391)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView.playAnimation(LottieAnimationView.java:511)
>            at com.beroozresaan.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity$1.onAnimationEnd(SplashActivity.java:196)
>            at android.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(Animator.java:552)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.BaseLottieAnimator.notifyEnd(BaseLottieAnimator.java:73)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.LottieValueAnimator.endAnimation(LottieValueAnimator.java:216)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.playAnimation(LottieDrawable.java:391)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView.playAnimation(LottieAnimationView.java:511)
>            at com.beroozresaan.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity$1.onAnimationEnd(SplashActivity.java:196)
>            at android.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(Animator.java:552)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.BaseLottieAnimator.notifyEnd(BaseLottieAnimator.java:73)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.LottieValueAnimator.endAnimation(LottieValueAnimator.java:216)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.playAnimation(LottieDrawable.java:391)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView.playAnimation(LottieAnimationView.java:511)
>            at com.beroozresaan.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity$1.onAnimationEnd(SplashActivity.java:196)
>            at android.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(Animator.java:552)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.BaseLottieAnimator.notifyEnd(BaseLottieAnimator.java:73)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.LottieValueAnimator.endAnimation(LottieValueAnimator.java:216)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.playAnimation(LottieDrawable.java:391)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView.playAnimation(LottieAnimationView.java:511)
>            at com.beroozresaan.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity$1.onAnimationEnd(SplashActivity.java:196)
>            at android.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(Animator.java:552)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.BaseLottieAnimator.notifyEnd(BaseLottieAnimator.java:73)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.utils.LottieValueAnimator.endAnimation(LottieValueAnimator.java:216)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.playAnimation(LottieDrawable.java:391)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable$2.run(LottieDrawable.java:380)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.setComposition(LottieDrawable.java:226)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView.setComposition(LottieAnimationView.java:460)
>            at com.beroozresaan.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity.lambda$loadDefaultFromAssets$1$SplashActivity(SplashActivity.java:136)
>            at com.beroozresaan.android.ui.splash.-$$Lambda$SplashActivity$Ggdzqtz0YkoM-aNiOz71rE-ohzo.onResult(:4)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask.notifySuccessListeners(LottieTask.java:144)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask.access$100(LottieTask.java:27)
>            at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask$1.run(LottieTask.java:131)
>            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
>            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
>            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
> ```

**SplashActivity.java**:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ErrorDialogFragment.OnErrorActionListener {

    @Inject
    ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory;

    private SettingViewModel settingViewModel;
    private ActivitySplashBinding mBinding;
    private boolean settingIsLoaded = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_splash);
        settingViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(SettingViewModel.class);

        subscribeSettingResponse();

        setAnimationListener();
    }

    private void loadSetting() {
        settingViewModel.loadSetting();
    }

    private void subscribeSettingResponse() {
        settingViewModel.getSettingResponse().observe(this, dataWrapper -> {
            switch (dataWrapper.status) {
                case SUCCESS:
                    settingIsLoaded = true;
                    break;
                case ERROR:
                case SERVER_ERROR:
                case CONNECTION_ERROR:
                    ErrorDialogFragment.showError(getSupportFragmentManager(), MessageMap.exceptionParser(this, dataWrapper), this);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    private void startMainActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null)
            intent.putExtras(getIntent().getExtras());
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        settingViewModel.getSettingResponse().removeObservers(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        playSplash();
        loadSetting();
    }
    

    private void playSplash() {
        String splashAnimationFileName = "splash_default.json";
        LottieTask lottieCompositionLottieTask = LottieCompositionFactory.fromAsset(this, splashAnimationFileName);

        lottieCompositionLottieTask.addListener(result1 -> {
            mBinding.animationLottie.setComposition(result1);
            mBinding.animationLottie.playAnimation();
        });

        lottieCompositionLottieTask.addFailureListener(result -> {
            Timber.e(result);
            startMainActivity();
        });

        mBinding.animationLottie.addAnimatorUpdateListener(animation -> {
            if (animation.isRunning()) {
                mBinding.animationLottie.removeAllUpdateListeners();
            }
        });

        mBinding.animationLottie.setFailureListener(result -> {
            Timber.e(result);
            startMainActivity();
        });

    }

    private void setAnimationListener() {
        mBinding.animationLottie.addAnimatorListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                Timber.e("animation started");
            }

            @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                if (settingIsLoaded) {
                    startMainActivity();
                } else {
                    mBinding.animationLottie.playAnimation();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                Timber.e("animation repeated");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mBinding != null) {
            mBinding.animationLottie.removeAllUpdateListeners();
            mBinding.animationLottie.removeAllLottieOnCompositionLoadedListener();
            mBinding.animationLottie.removeAllAnimatorListeners();
            mBinding = null;
        }

    }
}
```

**activity_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/animation_lottie"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove="false"
            app:lottie_renderMode="automatic"
            app:lottie_speed="1" />
 </layout>
```

Comment: actually I have found an issue on Lottie tracker and it seems the crash was resolved. The gist is - when animations are  disabled on a device Lottie  immediately calls onEndAnimation and if it has a trigger for a new animation then it loops.

Answer (score 0):

Lottie added a new function to ignore system animation settings completely. In that case, your animationEnd callback works properly,just add this function

```
 mBinding.animationLottie.setIgnoreDisabledSystemAnimations(true)
```

or from xml `app:lottie_ignoreDisabledSystemAnimations="true"`

by default, they are false.